# What happens to the executable when using the run command in the go compiler?

Tags: go, compilation

Using the `go build myprogam.go` produces an executable file, which is what I'm familiar with when working with compilers.

However, using `go run myprogram.go` doesn't create any executable files and still runs the program.

How exactly does this work, is the executable created and then deleted or does it run the code like an interpreter would?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A temporary executable is created.
The same is the case for go test.

Documentation on `go test`

`The package is built in a temporary directory so it does not interfere with the non-test installation.`

[Source](https://golang.org/cmd/go/)

You can also run `fmt.Println(os.Args[0])` to see the executable file that is being created.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. When is the temporary executable deleted? Right after the command or at some other time?

Comment: I'm not sure about that. But I'm guessing it would be deleted just after execution ends.